# Is it the "weight" or height and width that matters

Tags: ios, memory, image-size

I'm developing a game with lots of graphics for iOS platform. None of the graphics are dynamic, they're all ready made images. There are 6 layers on the screen and each layer contains 3-4 graphics objects in average that constantly scroll to left, each with different speeds. So with each screen refresh about 20-25 objects are scrolled, removed from screen and added again from right. The game is universal so images of all sizes present in the resources folder.On iPads, iPhone 5, iPhone 5s it goes smooth. But on 4th Gen iPod touch I notice some hiccup.
 When I test the app with Instruments, I notice a critic memory problem at start and then the problem goes away. So this is all because I load all the above graphics on application start. All the images are combined into 4 different sprite sheets. So here's my question:
  Is it the weight in kilobytes that matters or is it the dimensions? I'm asking this because I reduced the  size of the images by about 70-80 percents, though their height and width remain the same, but that memory problem still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are reducing the size of the images by utilizing compression, then expect there to be delay and a memory hit as the images are uncompressed when first loaded, and they will take up as much memory as they did before compression.

The 4th generation iPod Touch probably is having some memory pressures and it will try to release memory elsewhere in order to allow for your images to load up and stay in memory.  That may be the hiccup you see, as other apps, like Mobile Safari or Mail are asked to give up some memory or to terminate.

(The size the images take in the resources folder is inconsequential.  It is the size they take when they are uncompressed and in memory that matters).

You could make the images smaller by making them 4bit instead of 8bit color, or you could make them monochrome.  You can also use a non-retina size or smaller, and then let the OS stretch them out to fit the space required.  I would try to use the best images first, and if you get a memory warning (didReceiveMemoryWarning), then reload with the images that are less dense.

Answer (score 0):

you can not load all image before the game beginning, you should use the cache to control the size of the memory. And before the scenery of game change ,the release the cache ,reload the need ones.
So you must control your resource dependents in the every game scenery.
This is the common method to management the large resource application.

Comment: But what if I need all of them at startup?

Comment: if you need 'em all - you have to run some sort of fun animation while loading.

Comment: OK, I can do that, but what about the critic memory warning? I mean from user's point of view, that'll be OK, but there'll still be memory overhead in the background.

Comment: may be use the opgl api to rendering in the frame buffer, use the partly render tech at this buffer, when you use the target image ,load it and render, if not ,release them